# I can´t deploy or running my plugin (server side event handlers) in TFS 2012

Tags: plugins

I want to deploy [my plugin in TFS like this page says](http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/10/27/developing-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010/).

but my plugin doesn´t work. I have TFS 2012 and VS 2013. I put the DLL in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins but it looks like the plugin is never called. So nothing appears in the event log.

I try to debug the plugin attaching to Process to w3wp but debugging does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I must to have the same version in all the dlls:

TFS 2012:

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;                       Version 11

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;             Version 11
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;      Version 11